# Fire-and-forget background jobs using Azure Durable Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a use case which requires me to fire some Azure Durable Functions without caring about its results, and I was wondering if my approach is the correct one.

This is the scenario I'm in:

- Function `A` uses an `HttpTrigger`
- Function `B` uses an `ActivityTrigger`

This is my workflow:

- `A` is invoked and needs to do some business logic
- Alongside this business logic, I need to do a long background task that may or may not fail. I don't care about the results, but I need to run this task everytime `A` is invoked.
- `A` needs to return as quick as possible, that's why I can't wait for the background task to finish
- `B` takes care of this background task while `A` returns

All the Durable Functions examples that I'm finding online show something like this:

```
await starter.StartNewAsync("BackgroundDurableFunction", data)
```

My issue is here is that I don't want to `await` the Durable Function but I need it to just run in background and do its things (mostly network I/O).

To avoid waiting for this Durable Function I ended up with this workaround:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => starter.StartNewAsync("BackgroundDurableFunction", data));
```

This seems to work just right, as I don't need to `await` anything, but after reading [The Dangers of Task.Factory.StartNew](https://sergeyteplyakov.github.io/Blog/async/2019/05/21/The-Dangers-of-Task.Factory.StartNew.html) I'm a little bit scared that this might be a dangerous solution.

So, the question is: what's the correct way to start a Durable Function and have it run in background without caring about its results (and without having warnings about not waiting for the task)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, durable functions should work well for your scenario. You are just missing one thing: The Orchestrator. This should get you started:

```
[FunctionName("MyHttpTriggered")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log,
[OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient starter)
{
    string data = "hello";
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("MyOrchestrator", data);
    return new OkObjectResult($"Orchestrator started. Instance ID={instanceId}");
}

[FunctionName("MyOrchestrator")]
public static async Task MyOrchestrator(
[OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
{
    string data = context.GetInput<string>();
    await context.CallActivityAsync("YourActivityFunction", data);
}

[FunctionName("YourActivityFunction")]
public static async Task YourActivityFunction([ActivityTrigger] string data, ILogger log)
{

    // do whatever here

}
```

While there are `await` statements, this is truly fire and forget. The opposite would be a [fan-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup#the-functions) pattern. In this case you basically do a fan-out without the fan-in.

Comment: Actually `BackgroundDurableFunction` is my orchestrator, sorry for not making it clear enough. I'm not quite sure to understand what you mean: are you saying that, despite `await` being there, `starter.StartNewAsync` just fires the function without waiting for its results?

Comment: yes, because StartNewAsync does not produce any result - apart from the instance ID. See my full sample here which does a Fan-in https://github.com/sebader/alpinehutproject/blob/master/AzureFunctions/UpdateHutsFunctions.cs#L85

Comment: just give it a try ;)