# Azure Fire-And-Forget HTTP Request

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I want to create a very simple azure function to fire a post request and does not wait to the response.I want to make sure that the request is sent but I don't want to wait for the response. I really don't care about the response.

```
[FunctionName("FireForgetPostRequest")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "Post", Route = "MyTest")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        //Send Post Request to certain end point without validating the response
    }
```

Comment: ... Or you let the function await the request and leave it up to the caller of the azure function to await its response or not. If the request does not take long why bother with a fire-and-forget anyway?

Answer (score 0):

To record any exceptions, use `await` method in the task. As the user @*Silent* also specified that the truly fire and forget case happens when there are `await` statements in similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014215).

If your requests long time, then fan-in/fan-out pattern will help you accomplish the requirement in Azure durable Functions.

Thanks to @*PeterBons* for pointing the user in right direction that,

> you let the function await the request and leave it up to the caller of the azure function to await its response or not. If the request does not take long why bother with a fire-and-forget anyway?